# can't convert lists to tensor in tensorflow python

Tags: python, keras, nlp, tensorflow, rnn

I'm relatively new to ML and data science and I'm using tensorflow and keras to do a NLP project.
I have about 18000 emails, in my code I convert each word in every email to a vector of shape (1,50) and then add all those arrays to a list. Obviously the length of those lists are different. When trying to fit my model I receive error.
How my arrays look like:
 `[[float, float,....,float],[float, float,....,float],....]`
My code:

```
train_data, test_data=train_test_split(DataFrame_2,test_size=0.2, train_size=0.8,random_state=0,stratify=DataFrame['Label'])

#print(test_data)

#Creating the model as a function

def MyModel():
    model=Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.15))
    model.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.15))
    model.add(Dense(1,'relu'))
    optim=keras.optimizers.Adam()
    model.compile(optimizer=optim, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accurcay'])
    return model

model=MyModel()
model.fit(tf.convert_to_tensor(train_data["Body"]), train_data["Label"], batch_size=64, epochs=25, verbose=1, validation_split=0.20, use_multiprocessing=True)
```

What I have tried:

I tried used `convert_to_tensor()` function both in first line (where I'm splitting the data), where I was fitting the data and also where I was making the array of vectors like this:

```
for sent in tqdm(num_sent):
    vectorized.append([embedding_matrix_vocab[num] for num in sent])

DataFrame_2=pd.DataFrame({'Body':vectorized, "Label":DataFrame["Label"]})
```

also This is the error I'm receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Farbod\work\ml\spam detection\SpamDetection.py", line 245, in <module>
    model.fit(tf.convert_to_tensor(train_data["Body"]), train_data["Label"], batch_size=64, epochs=25, verbose=1, validation_split=0.20, use_multiprocessing=True)
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 102, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).
```

I have this guess which may or may not help. Since the sentences are of different sizes maybe converting them to tensor is not OK and maybe they should be converted to lists with fixed sizes.

Comment: Can you add a step after `train_data, test_data=train_test_split(DataFrame_2, ...` to create numpy arrays, passing those to the model instead of lists? In your case, because you pass a `pd.DataFrame` to [`train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html), you get a dataframe back. You can then access the underlying data as numpy arrays directly using the `.values` attribute e.g. on a column.  So try: `model.fit(train_data["Body"].values, train_data["Label"].values, ...)`.

Comment: @n1k31t4, thanks for your comment I tested what you said but it seems although it works on individual entries from the data frame it does not work on the whole thing. e.g: `model.fit(train_data["Body"].values[0], train_data["Label"].values, ...)` somehow works! but the one you said raises this exception: `ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).`

Comment: The full solution would be to instead create a [tf.data.Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) (e.g. using the `from_tensor_slices` method) from your dataframe. That allows you to specify the full shapes and batch size, etc. (among many other nice features). You'll be able to find tutorials on going from `pd.DataFrame` to `tf.data.Dataset`. The train/val datasets are then given directly to `model.fit()`.

Comment: @n1k31t4 so does that allow me to have lists with variable sizes as inputs? because zero padding and converting all the entries to same size is also seeming to be a choice.

Comment: There isn't a simple way to have variably sized input tensors. You can zero pad (you need to do that yourself), or you could explore Ragged Tensors, [which also integrate with tf.dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor#datasets).

Comment: You could also use an tokenization and encoding layers to encode all your emails into a latent tensor of fixed shape, which is then fed to the model.

Comment: @n1k31t4 I will test those and find the best way. You did a great help thanks.